# They were all sitting there primly dressed in their spring Sunday best

Tags: sentence-meaning

Quote:

They were all sitting there primly dressed in their spring Sunday best.

The story happened in the start of the fall semester. Why did they dress in their spring Sunday best? Is it one of the unwritten customs? What is spring Sunday? Does UK/Cananda have something equivalent?

Thanks for any reply that can shed some light on this one.

Comment: Dressing in one's Sunday best means wearing the special clothing normally reserved for church attendance, which is (for many families) a Sunday morning custom. I can't explain the seasonal references. Maybe spring and fall (in the setting of the story) have similar weather, so that clothing appropriate to one will be also appropriate to the other.

Comment: Conceivably it means what they would wear to church on Easter, a Sunday in spring when people are likely to wear their absolute best.

Comment: Yeah. I'm with Anton, whose explanation is better than the one I came back to suggest: maybe the idea of "spring" Sunday best is just the sort of clothing, lighter in weight and brightly colored, that a lot of people start wearing each year in the spring. I guess that according to either theory, it would then make no difference that the story is set in the autumn.

Comment: "Getting all dressed in my spring Sunday best is one of my favorite ways to start the week. Normally, my fancy attire can be shown off at church, but due to covid my family is all the audience I currently have." - https://corinneelise.com/spring-sunday-best/

Comment: The available analyses are [spring][Sunday best] (contrast the other Sunday best attire they possess, to be used in colder weather) (ie 'spring' an identifier) and [spring][Sunday best] (their only Sunday best attire, displayed in spring) (ie 'spring' used purely as a descriptor). Not [spring Sunday] [best].